# Change the order of returned posts

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have written a neat responsive slider for my Wordpress featured articles (feel free to use it):

```
<?php 
    $responsive = 'on' != get_option('henrik_responsive_layout') ? false : true;
    $featured_auto_class = '';
    if ( 'on' == get_option('henrik_slider_auto') ) $featured_auto_class .= ' et_slider_auto et_slider_speed_' . get_option('henrik_slider_autospeed');
?>
<div id="featured" class="<?php if ( $responsive ) echo 'flexslider' . $featured_auto_class; else echo 'et_cycle'; ?>">
    <a id="left-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Previous','henrik'); ?></a>
    <a id="right-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Next','henrik'); ?></a>

<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    <ul class="slides">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="slides">
<?php } ?>
        <?php global $ids;
        $ids = array();
        $arr = array();
        $i=0;

        $featured_cat = get_option('henrik_feat_cat'); 
        $featured_num = (int) get_option('henrik_featured_num'); 

        if (get_option('henrik_use_pages') == 'false') query_posts("showposts=$featured_num&cat=".get_cat_ID($featured_cat));
        else {
            global $pages_number;

            if (get_option('henrik_feat_pages') <> '') $featured_num = count(get_option('henrik_feat_pages'));
            else $featured_num = $pages_number;

            query_posts(array
                            ('post_type' => 'page',
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post__in' => (array) get_option('henrik_feat_pages'),
                            'showposts' => (int) $featured_num
                        ));
        } ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        global $post; ?>
        <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            <li class="slide">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="slide">
        <?php } ?>
                <?php
                $width = $responsive ? 960 : 958;
                $height = 340;
                $small_width = 95;
                $small_height = 54;
                $titletext = get_the_title();

                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Featured');

                $arr[$i]['thumbnail'] = get_thumbnail($small_width,$small_height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Small');
                $arr[$i]['titletext'] = $titletext;

                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
                print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>
                <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
                <div class="featured-bottom-shadow"></div>  
                <div class="featured-description">
                    <div class="feat_desc">
                        <p class="meta-info"><?php esc_html_e('Posted','henrik'); ?> <?php esc_html_e('by','henrik'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php esc_html_e('on','henrik'); ?> <?php the_time(esc_attr(get_option('henrik_date_format'))) ?></p>
                        <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p><?php truncate_post(410); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"><?php esc_html_e('Read More', 'henrik'); ?></a>
                </div> <!-- end .description -->
        <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            </li> <!-- end .slide -->
        <?php } else { ?>
            </div> <!-- end .slide -->
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $ids[] = $post->ID; $i++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    </ul> <!-- end .slides -->
<?php } else { ?>
    </div> <!-- end #slides -->
<?php } ?>
</div> <!-- end #featured -->

<div id="controllers" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $featured_num; $i++) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="controller">
                    <a href="#"<?php if ( $i == 0 ) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
                        <?php print_thumbnail( $arr[$i]['thumbnail']['thumb'], $arr[$i]['thumbnail']["use_timthumb"], $arr[$i]['titletext'], $small_width, $small_height ); ?>
                        <span class="overlay"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>  
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="active_item"></div>
</div> <!-- end #controllers -->
```

It selects a custom category and returns a custom amount of posts. The problem is that it will display the posts in the order of which they were created. **I want to choose my own order**, so that I can select which posts displays first and so on.

**So, is it possible to select which order the returned posts are displayed?** Maybe by targeting specific IDs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already doing this by using `'orderby' => 'menu_order'`. All you need to do now is set the menu order in the WordPress interface -- all new posts default to `0`. Or you change the `orderby` argument to [something else](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your respond, I am aware that I can change the orderby to various options, however, I am not familiar with how the menu_order solution would work? How can I set the menu_order in the Wordpress interface for **posts**?

Comment: Ah, you were using the `page` post type so I figured you had that option. Technically `menu_order` will work for all post types but there is no interface for non-hierarchical post types (i.e. posts). You could register a new post as hierarchical. It depends on your goal, but ordering blog posts doesn't make sense because you add more and keep them published a new post type might work for you.

Comment: The only one on the list that I want to select is the first one displayed. Can you find a way how to force the first display to be a custom ID (that I set directly in the code) and the rest to display as they are ordered when returned? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could setup two queries: one would search for the latest (or whatever order you choose) post with a given custom field. The second query could ignore that custom field and look for everything else as normal.

Comment: Oh right I see where you going with this, very good solution. If you have any time, can you please edit your answer by looking through my code and writing up these two queries and I can give this solution a shot?